# Where is $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH getting

Tags: macos, bash

`echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns `/Library/Oracle/lib` but I don't find anything in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.  I am using Mac OS X 10.8 and I don't have `.profile` file in my home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check

```
/etc/bashrc
```

or

```
/etc/profile
```